# java web application : take data from html table and store it to Mysql table

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

### actually am trying to get data from html table and store it to MYSQL table    using jQuery am able to get data from html table but not able to place it in mysql so for that I have to use jsp but I dont knw how can I pass multidimentional array to jsp can any one help me please

### my jquery code :

```
jQuery('#blBtnOk').on('click', function() {
                    var rows = [];
                    row = {};
     $("#tblSlctd tbody tr").each(function () {
                               row['name'] = ($(this).children('td:eq(0)').text());
                               row['qntity'] = ($(this).children('td:eq(1)').text());
                               rows.push(JSON.stringify(row));
                });
                  
      $.ajax({
          url: "abc.jsp",
          type: "post",
          data: {
              'rows[]': row
          },
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          success: function(msg) {
              alert("Successfully posted "+JSON.stringify(json));
          }
      });
```

### my abc.jsp code :

```
st.execute("insert into table1 values('"+ request.getParameter("name") + "', 12)");
```

Comment: The answer is JSON. You can pass a object array directly as an object in a post to a java class that does the insertion in mysql.

Comment: I tried with json in php but problem was at the php end i was not able to extract data

Comment: @sumitapatel most of the Backend languages like `php`, `java` etc has json parsers, if not built in, there are plugins like `Gson` from google (for `java`, i guess)

Comment: forget about php now I want to achive that through jsp can you help me

Comment: my code is some thing like this   $("#blBtnOk").on("click", function ()

      {

       var rows = [];

                                          row = {};

         $("#tblSlctd tbody tr").each(function () {
 
                                                    row['name'] = ($(this).children('td:eq(0)').text()); row['qntity'] = ($(this).children('td:eq(1)').text());

                                                     rows.push(JSON.stringify(row));
 $.ajax({
url: "abc.jsp",
 type: "POST",
 data: {
  'rows[]': row
  },

Comment: on abc.jsp page I want rows[] and extract name and qntity from it to store it in mysql individualy.

Comment: what is the code in your abv.jsp page?

Comment: The JSON is generated by the jquery, not php. make a object array from your data as explained here at the bottom end of this instruction page (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). Once you have that, you pass that object array to java and it handles it without a problem.

Comment: how can I assign 2d array passed by JQuery to an 2D array in Jsp ???

Comment: Only by sending it back to the server and have the server generate a new page.

Comment: not getting it if possible then please send me example

Comment: to Jkike :  it's code for retriving data from html table and store it to an aaray     in jQuery

Comment: see my proper code in question which is adding null & 12 to mysql table1